# How to generate and publish code coverage for integration tests without ssh into docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose, code-coverage, jacoco

I have a Spring boot application deployed using Docker compose, I need to generate and publish code coverage for my integration test (Running in Jenkins) using Jacoco and Sonarcube.

Below steps are working in my local

- Added jacoco dependency and plugin in pom.xml & started service using jacoco java agent
- Run integration tests
- Generate jacoco. exec file
- Publish to sonarcube

```
java -javaagent:org.jacoco.agent-0.8.10-runtime.jar=output=tcpserver,address=* -jar target/service.jar

mvn jacoco:dump -Djacoco.address=localhost

mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
```

This solution wont work in the container without ssh into it. Is there a better way to achieve this ?

I have also tried using https://hub.docker.com/r/ictu/jacoco-agent-docker, but above mentioned problem still exists in this case as well.

Comment: haven't found a better solution yet @max